# Relationship between Boolean algebras isomorphism and partially ordered sets isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Is the following proposition correct?

> Two Boolean algebras $B_1$ and $B_2$ are isomorphic (i.e., there exists a bijection $f$ from $B_1$ to $B_2$ under which the operations $+,\ast, '$ are preserved) if and only if they are isomorphic as ordered sets (i.e., there exists a bijection $f$ from $B_1$ to $B_2$ under which the ordering is preserved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Suppose $f: \mathbf{B}_1 \to \mathbf{B}_2$ is an order-isomorphism between the underlying posets.
Then $$a \leq b \Leftrightarrow f(a) \leq f(b).$$
Using this equivalence, it follows immediately that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=1$.
Also, since $a \wedge b \leq a$, we have $f(a \wedge b) \leq f(a)$; also $f(a \wedge b) \leq f(b)$, whence $f(a \wedge b) \leq f(a) \wedge f(b)$.
Now if $d \leq f(a) \wedge f(b)$, then, taking $c$ such that $f(c) = d$, we have $c \leq a, b$ because $f(c) = d \leq f(a), f(b)$. 
So $c \leq a \wedge b$ whence $d \leq f(a \wedge b)$.
$$\therefore f(a) \wedge f(b) = f(a \wedge b).$$
Analogously $f(a) \vee f(b) = f(a \vee b)$.

Now 
$$0 = f(0) = f(a \wedge a') = f(a) \wedge f(a'),$$
and analogously, $1 = f(a) \vee f(a')$, and therefore $f(a') = f(a)'$.

Comment: Thanks. How is $f(a) \land f(b) = f(a \land b)$ followed from that "$c \le a \land b$ whence $d \le f(a \land b)$"?

Comment: I took $d$ to be a lower bound of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and concluded that it is a lower bound of $f(a \wedge b)$; so $f(a \wedge b)$ is the infimum of $\{f(a),f(b)\}$, that is, $f(a) \wedge f(b)$.

Comment: @hengxin By the way, I forgot the other implication (that if two Boolean Algebras are isomorphic, then so are their underlying posets) but I take that you were only asking about the implication I proved, while this other one is more or less trivial...